# The wp-config.php in WordPress website auto change the database configuration to "test"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and it works well in a year. 
But I get the error "error establishing a database connection" recently.
I noticed the database configuration (database name, user, password) was changed to the "test" in **wp-config.php**:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'test');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test');
```

I changed the database information to correctly and it back works well. But the error back to after some days and the database configuration auto change back to "test". I also changed the FTP account and the error still repeat.
I don't know why. Please help me, Thanks!

Comment: Check if there is no files from duplicator (installer.php) in the root of your website.

Comment: Thank you for supporting. I will try this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it changes because you perform a restore. It is good to create a file in the production with name "foo.txt". and write a code that is going to say

If file   exist
then use configuration for production
else if file does not exist
then use configuration for test

Then when you make the restore to test you have to delete
every time the file foo.txt

```
if [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ]
then
     define('DB_NAME', 'prod');
     define('DB_USER', 'prod');
     define('DB_PASSWORD', 'prod');
else
   define('DB_NAME', 'test');
   define('DB_USER', 'test');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test');
fi
```

Try it I did not run it